# OpenStreetMap Android MapView load Tiles after Zoom

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, osmdroid

i am developing an android app using osmdroid. I am drawing an overlay on the map, depending where your current location is. Depending on the zoomlevel should the overlay get more details (level of detail). In other words, i have to draw the overlay on every zoomlevel. My Problem is the onCreate function is called only once and so is my function to draw the overlay.
I have to optimize the overlay algorithm. The overlay i am drawing on the map should be detailed as necessary and not more. On a zoomlevel of 0, it is not necessary to draw a little polygon with several thousands points.

Comment: You could have a look at implementing the [MapListener](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/events/MapListener.html) interface in your Activity and receive `onZoom(ZoomEvent event)` events when the zoom level changes. And maybe update your question with details, if you run into troubles.

Comment: Thanks Markus, i will try that.